# Notation for square root of positive-definite matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

Why is the real square root notation $\sqrt{~~~}$ not used for matrices (as far as I know)? The square root of a matrix is not uniquely defined in general, but could the notation $\sqrt{~~~}$ be used in the context of positive-definite matrices?

Comment: I think it's mostly due to the fact that powers of matrices are a very common operation. In terms of functions of matrices, only $e^A$ is a really frequent function of a matrix - note that we even write $A^{-1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{A}$.

Comment: If $x$ is a scalar, its rational powers are usually written in the form of $x^{m/n}$ rather than $\sqrt[n]{x^m}$ in the literature. Admittedly, when $\frac mn=\frac12$, the notation $\sqrt{x}$ may be more popular than $x^{1/2}$, yet I don't think the near-ubiquitous use of the notations like $A^{1/2}$ for matrix square roots is something especially curious.

Answer (score 3):

The most common notation is $A^{1/2}$.

Indeed, is $A$ is symmetric and positive (semi)definite, then it is diagonalizable and hence $A=U^*DU$, where $D=\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ is a diagonal matrix containing the non-negative eigenvalues of $A$ in the diagonal. Clearly, is
$$
B=U^*D^{1/2}U,\quad \text{where}\quad D^{1/2}=\mathrm{diag}(d_1^{1/2},\ldots,d_n^{1/2}),
$$
then $B^2=A$.

Hence, it is *plausible* to define the square root of $A$ as $U^*D^{1/2}U$.

Comment: Yes, but why is $A^{1/2}$ used, rather than $\sqrt{A}$? Are there typographical reasons, for example?

Comment: It's not only plausible. The functional calculus for self-adjoint operators allows to define $f(A)$ e.g. for functions $f$ which are continuous on the spectrum of the self-adjoint operator $A$. Symmetric matrices can be identified with self-adjoint operators and from the positive-semidefiniteness follows that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$  is continuous on the spectrum.